# set knockout checkbox label css-cursor from pointer to not-allowed

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

When the `SelectAllActiveEnabled` is true the checkbox is clickable and the css cursor value is pointer. When the `SelectAllActiveEnabled` evaluates to false the checkbox is not clickable bút the css cursor value is still pointer. How do I set it to not-allowed?

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAllActiveReleases, enable: SelectAllActiveEnabled" />
    @Html.GetTranslation(Center.Infrastructure.TranslationSources.Center_Web_Orders_ReleaseFull_ReleaseOverview_LabelSelectAllActiveReleases)
</label>
```

Comment: Use the `:enabled` CSS selector to modify the cursor. Don't bother doing that with knockout.

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for "pure knockout" solution you should use `style` binding like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAllActiveReleases, enable: SelectAllActiveEnabled, style:{'cursor': cursorForCheckbox()}" />
```

You'll have to introduce `cursorForCheckbox` to your View Model. Something like this:

```
self.cursorForCheckbox = ko.pureComputed(function() {return self.SelectAllActiveEnabled() ? 'pointer' : 'not-allowed';});
```